# Find probability that false chicken weights 3kg

Tags: probability

Let's have 10 chickens. Real chicken weights 2kg. We know that among those 10 chickens one is false and it weights 1kg with probability $\dfrac12$ or 3kg with probability $\dfrac12$.

We have a machine.
Machine is picking (independly from others) $i$-th chicken with probability $\dfrac12$ for weighting. After a weighting we return all chickens to the machine.

We have 3 weightings. First set of chickens (we don't know the quantity) weights 11kg, second set 12kg and third set 13kg. What is the probability that false chicken weights 3kg?

My idea: 
F - weight of false chicken

X - weight of set of chickens

We need to calculate

$$P(F = 3kg) = P(F = 3kg | X = 11kg)P(X=11kg) +
 P(F=3kg | X=12kg)P(X=12kg) + P(F=3kg|X=13kg)P(X=13kg)$$

I'm having a lot of doubts about this solution. It might be OK, because probability that false chicken weights 1kg is the same as probability that false chicken weights 3kg (what should i change there if those probabilities weren't equal?)

I'd love to hear some hints or solutions to this. Cheers

Comment: You do realize that my question was for answers, not for comments. (Yes, I asked that question on meta)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the final answer, but here is my progress.

Firstly, since the second set is an even value, it can not have a 'false' chicken, whether $1$ kg or $3$ kg, so we can ignore it.

A. If the 'false' chicken is $1$ kg, the sets are:
a) 5 true, 1 false
b) 6 true, 1 false

B. If the 'false' chicken is $3$ kg, the sets are:
a) 4 true, 1 false
b) 5 true, 1 false

As all cases include the false chicken, let us assume that the false chicken is the first one and take into account only the other 9.

So, P(chicken is $3$ kg)=[P(select $4$ of $9$)+P(select $5$ of $9$)]/[P(select $4$ of $9$)+P(select $5$ of $9$)]+[P(select $5$ of $9$)+P(select $6$ of $9$)]